# Show another activity when no internet connection

Tags: android-wifi, internet-connection

I am working on a webview client app in Android Studio. 
I have a working splashscreen.

I want to check the internet connection, or check if the webpage is available.
If not, then go to another activity than my webview activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple thing load the webpage using custom WebViewClient overriding onPageError Method and starting The Activity in That Method.

```
class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient(){ 
onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error){


startActivity(new Intent(this,Your_Second Activity.class));



   }}
```

And set WebView Client Like

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

Comment: If this doesn't works try this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android?rq=1